# How to get rid of supplementary data provided by scipy(statistics)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I performed Mann-Whitney test

```
import pandas

from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

print(mannwhitneyu(k1, k2))
```

The problem is that I need the bare numbers, without additional information, because I want my script to generate a table with these values. How to remove all unnecessary?

Example(Thick marked that should remain):

```
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3201.5, pvalue=**0.21078755520484055**)
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3241.0, pvalue=**0.28793629902718276**)
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3240.0, pvalue=**0.16166098643677973**)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
>>> mannwhitneyu(k1, k2).pvalue
0.21078755520484055
>>> mannwhitneyu(k1, k2).statistic
3201.5
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please suggest whether there is the same function in scipy, which would allow to make an adjustment of p-value to the multuplicity? I have 194 different observations(k1 and k2) and it needs to be corrected.

Comment: BH(Bennamini and Hochbberg) adjustment

Comment: If you have time, you can answer here so I can accept you answer else. To grasp the meaning of the topic is not necessary. The point in the comment above)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433424/p-value-adjustment-mann-whitney-u-test-in-python

Comment: oooooh! What is the value of this parameter: '.statistics'?